# Mac app crashes on launch, linked framework not bundled

Tags: frameworks, nsbundle, mac-app-store

(Edit: I was able to bundle the framework but it still would not take the changed installation directory. So, below, the question has changed to "linked and bundled framework image not found")

The Mac app was submitted to MAS but rejected by Apple, for a very reasonable reason: a framework that was linked was not bundled.

I simply ask how I can make sure it is included correctly in the bundle, and confirm that on my Mac before submitting again.

Please let me know what/any extra information you need from me.

Edit: More information after following subzero's instructions.

When going Product > Build, .app files end up in Documents/build/Release on my machine.

Here's how my build phases look - https://dl.dropbox.com/u/19155207/copyframeworks.jpg

and a UIKit.Framework *folder* is inside WinKonto.app/Contents/Frameworks containing this: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/19155207/frameworksfolder.jpg

It still gives the same error if I run it from the Releases folder. Only when I run it from XCode it works. Can you see something wrong?

Edit 2: I've gotten the framework file (UIKit) into the bundle.

Here is the crash report error message:

> Dyld Error Message:   Library not loaded:
>   Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Versions/A/UIKit   Referenced from:
>   /Users/henrikerlandsson/Documents/build/Release/WinKonto.app/Contents/MacOS/WinKonto
>   Reason: image not found

But the framework is in the bundle, and it was modified by install_name_tool before being added to the project.

I don't know why that modification didn't work, but I made it a private framework instead and changed the installation directory there instead, and it worked (see my answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it a private framework. I followed the instructions under [Embedding a Private Framework in Your Application Bundle](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Tasks/CreatingFrameworks.html), and that let me set the framework's Installation Directory properly to where it appeared in the bundle.

Answer (score 1):

In XCode,

1. Add a Copy Files build phase to your application's target
2. Move this above the Link phase set its destination to myApp.app/Contents/Frameworks and add the framework to it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer :) But... I do have a Copy Frameworks phase (containing the framework in question) after the Link Frameworks phase. Do you mean that I also have to copy it to the bundle as a file? Also, I would appreciate some method of testing it's included properly before submitting. To not have to wait another 2 weeks, I mean.

Comment: well... after you copy the file to the Frameworks folder on the bundle with the copy files phase...
xcode will copy as well link your application to that bundle. Now to test - make a vm with vanilla mac os installed... copy your bundle there and run it... if it runs then you shouldn't have a problem

Comment: I don't do it with the Copy Files phase but another phase which seems to be made for copying frameworks, namely the Copy Frameworks phase. Does that phase copy the framework to somewhere else than the bundle? I've also not handled Mac bundles manually before, so I honestly don't know how to find it and copy it to another guy's machine. Is there an .app file somewhere?

Comment: which version of xcode are you using? in 4.5 which I have... you dont have any build phase specifically for copying frameworks... do you mean copy files build phase with "Frameworks" as the target.... that will work fine....

as for the built .app bundle, it will be in the derived data folder set in xcode(Preferences>Locations)... by default ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
so you should look in
~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<projectName+weird_string>/Build/Products
for the .app file

Comment: When going Product > Build, .app files end up in Documents/build/Release on my machine. Here's how my build phases look - https://dl.dropbox.com/u/19155207/copyframeworks.jpg and a UIKit.Framework *folder* is inside WinKonto.app/Contents/Frameworks containing this: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/19155207/frameworksfolder.jpg It still gives the same error if I copy-paste the app elsewhere on my Mac's harddisk. Can you see something wrong here?

Comment: Seems it wants it in *.app/Contents/MacOS/Frameworks instead. I will try this now.

Comment: Thanks for the time you put in trying to help me. But this wasn't the solution, and it isn't enough to do 1 and 2 to get the installation dir to work. Destination should normally just be Frameworks, but it can be anywhere in the the bundle as long as the installation dir is set to the same.